# How big can be ubyte[] in D?

Tags: arrays, d

Is there any limitation of maximum size of `ubyte[]` in D?

In [this](http://forum.dlang.org/post/fsasgxlrnvcktsixaylu@forum.dlang.org) thread I am getting out of memory error, and can't understand is it's issue with driver or limit of size of `ubyte[]`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The maximum length of any array in D is size_t.max.
However you will not be able to get anywhere near that in reality because of RAM limitations (and possibly swap too).

Comment: and memory fragmentation is a limit too.